# Fetch only headers of a GET request in Node

Tags: node.js, http, get, http-headers

I need to get the `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers of *large* files with Node.

Unfortunately, the server I'm dealing with doesn't allow `HEAD` requests, and the files are too large to make an entire `GET` request.

I'm looking for something like this python code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
content_length = r.headers['Content-Length']
content_type = r.headers['Content-Type']
```

The `stream=True` parameter means that the file won't be fully downloaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the `request` package, you could do something like this:

```
const request = require('request');
const r = request(url);
r.on('response', response => {
    const contentLength = response.headers['content-length'];
    const contentType = response.headers['content-type'];
    // ...
    r.abort();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The http library of nodejs by default it will not fetch everything but give the callback will contain the IncomingMessage object, to construct the full response you would have to listen to .on('data').

Take a look at:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

If you then want to "ignore" the incoming data, you can just call res.abort(). Calling this will cause remaining data in the response to be dropped and the socket to be destroyed.

Comment: This didn't work for me. In the `http.get` callback I added a `res.on('data', ...)`, but the inner callback didn't get called. I'm guessing it would have been called with the entire file as the chunk.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `method: 'HEAD'`:

```js
http.request('http://example.com', {
    method: 'HEAD',
}, res => {
    console.log(res.statusCode, res.statusMessage)
    console.log(res.headers)

    res.on('data', _ => {
        console.log(`IT SHOULDN'T REACH HERE!`)
    })
}).on('error', console.error)
  .end()
```

Comment: The OP says the server does not support `HEAD`.